# MySQL Join of two SELECT result

Tags: mysql, select, join, average

I have two select:

```
SELECT ID, ID_cat, modello 
FROM tbArticoli 
WHERE ID_cat=5
```

Example result in Json:

```
{"ID":"5","ID_cat":"5","modello":"Hawaii"},
{"ID":"6","ID_cat":"5","modello":"T-Shirt Righe"},
{"ID":"7","ID_cat":"5","modello":"Polo"},
{"ID":"8","ID_cat":"5","modello":"Fantasia"},
{"ID":"9","ID_cat":"5","modello":"Fiori"},
{"ID":"10","ID_cat":"5","modello":"Arcobaleno"},
{"ID":"11","ID_cat":"5","modello":"Oro"},
{"ID":"12","ID_cat":"5","modello":"Argento"},
{"ID":"13","ID_cat":"5","modello":"StelleStrisce"}
```

And another select:

```
SELECT IDModello, 
FLOOR(AVG(voto)) AS votomedio 
FROM tbCommenti 
GROUP BY IDModello
```

with result:

```
{"IDModello":"5","votomedio":"7"},
{"IDModello":"6","votomedio":"7"},
{"IDModello":"7","votomedio":"8"},
{"IDModello":"8","votomedio":"6"}
```

I need a final result like this:

```
{"ID":"5","ID_cat":"5","modello":"Hawaii","votomedio":"7"},
{"ID":"6","ID_cat":"5","modello":"T-Shirt Righe","votomedio":"7"},
{"ID":"7","ID_cat":"5","modello":"Polo","votomedio":"8"},
{"ID":"8","ID_cat":"5","modello":"Fantasia","votomedio":"6"},
{"ID":"9","ID_cat":"5","modello":"Fiori","votomedio":"null"},
{"ID":"10","ID_cat":"5","modello":"Arcobaleno","votomedio":"null"},
{"ID":"11","ID_cat":"5","modello":"Oro","votomedio":"null"},
{"ID":"12","ID_cat":"5","modello":"Argento","votomedio":"null"},  
{"ID":"13","ID_cat":"5","modello":"StelleStrisce","votomedio":"null"}

on tbArticoli.ID = tbCommenti.IDModello
```

Which is the best query?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to join on id = idmodello, you can do something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT ID, ID_cat, modello 
          FROM tbArticoli 
          WHERE ID_cat=5) AS tbA
LEFT JOIN (SELECT IDModello, 
          FLOOR(AVG(voto)) AS votomedio 
          FROM tbCommenti 
          GROUP BY IDModello) as tbC
ON tbA.ID = tbC.IDModello
```

You can specify subqueries as what you are selecting from, because MySQL selects from a set of tuples. The table name just specifies that you want all tuples from that table, whereas in the query above you are specifying the specific tuples that you want. The main thing to note in this query is that you must use the 'AS' keyword to specify a temp name for each set of tuples.

Comment: It works, but I need all tuples of tbArticoli table with "votomedio" column 'null' too.

Comment: Change `JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`. I will edit my response

Comment: Glad to hear! Happy to help.

Comment: This is the final query, without IDModello column and value:

 

    SELECT ID, ID_cat, modello, votomedio
     FROM (SELECT * 
     FROM tbArticoli 
     WHERE ID_cat=5) AS tbA
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT IDModello, 
     FLOOR(AVG(voto)) AS votomedio 
     FROM tbCommenti 
     GROUP BY IDModello) as tbC
     ON tbA.ID = tbC.IDModello